# Declined flags which report a move to Code review

Tags: discussion, migrated-questions, code-review-se

I'm new here in Meta Stack Overflow, but after research I got a small idea about the migration rules.

Recently (today), some of my flags has been declied by moderators and all was about "moving the question to CodeReview"

Some questions:

- [Optimized functions to compute projection of a point on a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087193/optimized-functions-to-compute-projection-of-a-point-on-a-line)
- [C# console random number guess game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121965/c-sharp-console-random-number-guess-game)

While I understand why the flag to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248050/is-it-ok-to-affect-boolean-while-testing) question has been declied (the author totally rewrote it!) I don't understand why the other flags to the questions linked above was declied.

After a bit of research I found this

> 1. It needs to be off topic for the source site, and it must be on topic for the target site. If a question is on topic for the source
>      site, then it generally should not be moved.
> 2. It *must* be a high quality post.  If you would vote to close the post on the source site (with the exception of off topic), then it
>      more than likely be closed for the same reason on the destination
>      site.  [We don't migrate crap.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248050/is-it-ok-to-affect-boolean-while-testing)
> 3. The post should be recent.  Depending on the destination, migrating the post could have a number of negative impacts such as the
>      OP not being registered on the destination site, the OP losing rep on
>      the source site and more.  Note that in the case where the question
>      has no answers, this does not always apply.
> 4. The post should not have an accepted answer or a lot of answers. Either one is usually an indication that the problem's been solved; so
>      migrating it won't really allow for new or better answers.
>
> Please keep these guidelines in mind when flagging posts for
>   migration. If too many of your flags are declined, your flag weight
>   will drop and your flags will become meaningless.

I think all the rules listed are respected, the two posts are **very high** quality posts (for me at least) and fits CodeReview rules.

When I flag the question (the same moment when the question was posted) no answer/comments was posted (except mine where I alerts the user about CodeReview was a better site) so the last point was OK too.

I think the problem is: the flags was around for a large time, so the questions gets answers (yup, great.) and my flags becomes "stupids"...  but it's right to decline a flag in their conditions? Should the flags become "invalid" after some time?

I should admit after reading the declied flags I just thought about "I understand correctly when a question should be moved to CR?"

I love CodeReview (when users don't post 1200 lines of code and wants a review, lol) so every time appears a question in SO where someone asks about a review I always link CodeReview site to let users know about this great site.

But at this point: I should continue to flag questions with this reason? We should admit that, since CodeReview is still beta, a user could get more answer in SO than CR but the two sites have two differents scopes! (but again, it could be on-topic in CR and SO)

How can CodeReview get more visibility if we continue to ignore it and respond to his questions?

Anyway I noticed this thing just today because I was about to flag a question and gets the message

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

After all I don't care about declied flag counter, I just want to help if possible, I just got there questions and would love to get how should I behave in there cases.. just answer the question with a review?

Comment: Possibly related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site

Comment: There's a comment from you on the first question you linked to that says "You don't know if it works and you already want to improve it?" As I recall, codereview is only for code which is *known to work*.

Comment: The second question has a comment from the OP on the accepted answer saying they've posted their code on codereview. Maybe they did it before the flag was handled by a moderator.

Comment: @Louis Yes, but the comment become out-dated in the same moment because he just writed wrong. See his edit queue. "write--optimize"

Comment: Yes, now that you direct me to the edit history, I see why you made your comment on the first question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I declined those flags. I decline *most* flags for migration to Code Review. In nearly every case, the questions flagged are either not very good, or *not off-topic on Stack Overflow!*

In this case, I found that:

- The questions were not very well specified (optimized *for what?* Speed? Memory use? Both? Are there architectural constraints? *Is there actually a problem* or are you just micro-optimizing for something to do? If so, what is the problem - what's your target for improvement?)
- The questions were on-topic for Stack Overflow. (This is usually a show-stopper right here, but I'll go on because I always check one other thing...)
- The questions were *already answered*. What's the point of relocating a not-so-great on-topic question when it already has what appear to be answers that were acceptable to the asker? Even if the question was *awesome*, why move it from an established site to a beta site when it doesn't need further answers? In cases where a nominally on-topic question is languishing on SO, I'll gladly move it elsewhere if there's a reasonable chance it'll get answered there - but I'm not fond of busywork, and that's what migrating these would've amounted to.

In your defense, the questions may *not* have been answered when you flagged them. We're working through a bit of a backlog right now, and I'm afraid some of these flags hung around a bit too long.

#### See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226574/should-the-question-looking-for-help-reducing-if-statements-be-migrated-to-code/226609#226609

Comment: About what you said when i flagged the question it fits the rules (as i said in the question), about the "we don't move to beta sites" well.. it's sad but ok.

Comment: What's the point of migrating unanswered questions? They can be re-asked: in that case migration only makes user experience a bit better for askers who didn't check the site's topic before posting. Where migration helps is preserving existing answers on a question that isn't suitable where it stands. (Of course if the question is on-topic where it is, it shouldn't be migrated.)

Comment: The point, @gilles, is that for an on-topic question, the potential of getting an answer elsewhere is worth migration if it is being ignored where it sits.

Answer (score 20):

I personally **hate** that the current behavior for migration is to flag the post for moderators. A lot of us don't really participate on other sites past Stack Overflow, and wouldn't know the rules of what's on-topic there any more than a regular user. Yet, for some reason, we're asked to make final decisions on *tons* of migration flags.

To be quite honest, I only ever look through them to see if they should be declined for an obvious reason (like being past the 60 day mark already), and otherwise ignore them. Obviously I don't want to migrate something if I'm not sure, but asking other site mods is time consuming and would become annoying with the volume of such flags we accumulate.

That being said, keep it in mind when you flag for migration. We do get a *lot* of them and most of them are on mediocre posts that we *just don't care* about. Unless the question is truly outstanding and makes our eyes pop, we aren't going to rush to take action on it and it will probably end up declined in the end, whenever someone decides to *just get it out of the queue*.

Until they implement some better method of getting questions migrated to other sites *without* also increasing the rejection rate on those migrations, the migration tool itself will remain flawed and limited. If you really feel a question should be on a different site and it doesn't have answers yet, I'd honestly recommend telling the OP to delete it on SO and re-post it on the other site rather than flagging in hopes that we'll move it for you. It'll get moved a lot quicker, if at all.

Comment: I should admit i understand you, moderators have better things to check but wouldn't be better if moderators of destination site could check there flags? Maybe they care (maybe they ignore them too (i'm sure they don't care at all too)).. Anyway i always write a comment with the flag because i just noticed there flags are ignored at all i'll start to write a comment and stop (Maybe the users will learn better which site they should choose before post a question). So i avoid to fill the queue with useless flags. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @Marco If you want, maybe accept Shog's answer below. His answer is more directed at your specific flags, while mine is more directed at flagging for migration in general. :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks you too anyway.

Comment: Does a flag for migration work differently from voting to close as belong on another network site?

Comment: @nhgrif this is especially about the fact that migrations to [codereview.se] never actually can be solved by users. CR is not a migration option for users. Every suggestion is a custom flag...